# Straight bar Latex

Tags: math-mode, formatting

How to write the straight bar with subscript as I have attached in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\left. \frac{dY}{dx_p} \right|_{p=1}
```

This code renders the "fraction" `dY/dx_p` surrounded by two large "bracket" symbols. The left bracket symbol is actually no symbol at all, and the right bracket is a vertical line.

And by the way, I usually want the "d" to be straight up, so I would write (with some help from Torbjørn T.):

```
\left. \frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}x_p} \right|_{p=1}
```

Comment: But the code showing latex error.

Comment: Don't use `\rm`, it has been deprecated for 20 years.  See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516) You want `\mathrm{d}`.

Comment: I'd also recommend manual scaling, in some situations autoscaling results in an excessively large vertical bar.